# windows 7 stuck on starting windows, hard drive error, trying to boot safe mode

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot

Machine getting stuck on booting windows 7.
i narrowed down to one of my hard drives, removing that hard drive allows windows to boot fine.

However, i cant boot into repair or safe mode if i attach that hd again. Is there anyway to do that to try and test/recover that hd?

Just before this happened, chkdsk was running during boot but froze after successfully completing the 3rd step. I did a hard reboot...

Win 7 event log has just 2 entries of bad block on disk and one entry of transaction manager on volume encountered a non retryable error and could not start.

This <1y wd green 3tb is now making a 5 sec repeating but feint clicking sound... my >5y wd 750gb is my primary and working fine.

Comment: Not a good situation to be in. My only advise really is to either pop it in another machine and see if it also affects booting or a better solution IMO is to purchase a cheap Hard Drive USB enclosure and pop the drive in there. This way you plug the USB in whilst in Windows and then try to get your data/repair the drive.

Comment: It sounds like the drive is dead.  The reason Windows cannot boot is it continuously attempts to mount the drive and fails and/or the drive does mount but then unmounts itself and a vicious cycle repeats.

Comment: attache the hard disk in another machine and check chkdsk for the hardisk. Also check the sata port whether any issue is there in the secondary port in that machine

Comment: or try mounting it from an external USB enclosure, that you can connect after the machine has booted, which would also prevent SMART getting in the way.

Comment: If it's a SATA drive you should be able to hot-swap it in while the OS is running as well.

Comment: Hd appears to be still alive!...

Comment: booted up system restore cd from an iso downloaded onto my primary hd. Testdisk utility on that linux distro can see the "broken" hd and its partitions. Currently trying to recover data now, i think one of partitions table broke down. However i dont know why win 7 wouldn't just skip that volume and continue to boot normally so it gives me a chance to fix it directly.

Comment: Nope, its dying. Enabled AHCI for hotswap and the partitions are only sometimes accessible. During testdisk analysis (which refuses to run on win 7 probably because it relies on win ddls for hd access), there was a horrible grinding sound lasting 10 secs. WD data lifeguard tests also fail. Now trying to backup whatever I can at 400kb/sec. Thanks for the tips. Hopefully WD rma doesnt suck as bad as what Ive read.